# Проигрывание музыки из iTunes одновременно с музыкой в приложении

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

В приложении есть функция звукового оповещения (мелодия), функция включается и отключается. Мелодии воспроизвожу с помощью AVAudioPlayer. При прослушивании музыки из iTunes и начале использования приложения, с включенным звуковым оповещением, музыка из iTunce перестает играть. Как сохранить проигрывание музыки из iTunes с включенным оповещением.
Пример использования AVAudioPlayer

```
var startedAudioPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: NSLocalizedString("workout-started", comment:""), ofType: "wav")!))

startedAudioPlayer?.play()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо настроить аудиосессию приложения используя константы AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDuckOthers и AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionInterruptSpokenAudioAndMixWithOthers

```
OSStatus status;
NSError *err;
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setActive:NO error:nil];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                    mode:AVAudioSessionModeDefault
                 options:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDuckOthers| AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionInterruptSpokenAudioAndMixWithOthers
                   error:&err];
[session setActive:YES error:&err];
```